# python - KeyError: 'PROGRAMFILES'\r: when calling .py from cgi

Tags: python, python-2.7

***UPDATE at bottom

I am building a simple webpage that I am using to launch some python scripts via cgi. I am running into an issue on one of my scripts that uses the scapy library. It appears that as scapy is imported I am running into a possible path issue (from the research I've done). I don't have this issue when running from the console or from a frozen pyinstaller .exe.

Running Python 2.7

Apache on Windows 7

This is what I'm getting traceback wise from my Apache error logs (I've cleaned up some unnecessary stuff from the output to make it easier to read)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\r: 
File "C:/Apache24/cgi-bin/host-lookup-trace.py", line 3, in <module>\r: 
from scapy.all import *\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\all.py", line 11, in 
<module>\r: 
from scapy.config import *\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\config.py", line 15, in 
<module>\r: 
from scapy.data import *\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\data.py", line 240, in 
<module>\r: 
MANUFDB = load_manuf(os.environ["ProgramFiles"] + 
"\\\\wireshark\\\\manuf")\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__\r: 
return self.data[key.upper()]\r: 

KeyError: 'PROGRAMFILES'\r:
```

In my shell, I get

```
os.environ["ProgramFiles"]
'C:\\Program Files'
```

As a test, I did the following in my scapy\data.py file

```
#MANUFDB = load_manuf(os.environ["ProgramFiles"] + "\\wireshark\\manuf")
 MANUFDB = load_manuf("C:\\\\Program Files\\\\wireshark\\\\manuf")
```

Same error with os.environ, just in a different call now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\r: 
File "C:/Apache24/cgi-bin/host-lookup-trace.py", line 3, in <module>\r:

from scapy.all import *\r: 
File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\all.py", line 16, in 
<module>\r: 
from scapy.arch import *\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\arch\\__init__.py", line 70, 
in <module>\r: 
from scapy.arch.windows import *\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\arch\\windows\\__init__.py", 
line 317, in <module>\r: 
conf.prog = WinProgPath()\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\arch\\windows\\__init__.py", 
line 288, in __init__\r: 
self._reload()\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\arch\\windows\\__init__.py", 
line 301, in _reload\r: 
self.wireshark = win_find_exe("wireshark", "wireshark")\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\scapy\\arch\\windows\\__init__.py", 
line 277, in win_find_exe\r: 
path = _where(fn, dirs=[os.path.join(os.environ[env], installsubdir)])\r: 

File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\os.py", line 425, in __getitem__\r: 
[return self.data[key.upper()]\r: 

KeyError: 'PROGRAMFILES'\r:
```

Hoping the great minds here can help me get to the bottom of this! I can post any further information as requested.

***UPDATE

I took out the import scapy line and I just tried to import os and then print the os.environ string. I get the same error, just not sure why calling this from within cgi is breaking this.

```
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>    Python 2.7.13: C:\Python27\Python.exe
Wed Dec 20 16:04:55 2017
A problem occurred in a Python script. Here is the sequence of function 
calls leading up to the error, in the order they occurred.

C:\Apache24\cgi-bin\host-lookup-trace.py in ()
32 print '<input type = \"submit\" value = \"Submit Selected Host\" />'
33 print '</form>' 
=>  34 print os.environ["ProgramFiles"]
35 print '<body>\n\n'
36 print '</html>\n\n'
os = <module 'os' from 'C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc'>, os.environ = 
{'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://127.0.0.1/host-lookup-t...'1', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
C:\Python27\lib\os.py in __getitem__(self={'HTTP_REFERER': 
'http://127.0.0.1/host-lookup-t...'1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, 
deflate, br'}, key='ProgramFiles')
423                 self.data[key.upper()] = item
424             def __getitem__(self, key):
=>  425                 return self.data[key.upper()]
426             try:
427                 unsetenv
self = {'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://127.0.0.1/host-lookup-t...'1', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, br'}, self.data = {'COMSPEC': 
r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '26', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT': 
'c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/', 'CONTEXT_PREFIX': '/cgi-bin/', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': 
'C:/Apache24/htdocs', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'HTTP_ACCEPT':
```

'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*
    ;q=0.8', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 
    'en-US,en;q=0.9', ...}, key = 'ProgramFiles', key.upper = 
    : 'PROGRAMFILES' 
    args = ('PROGRAMFILES',) 
    message = 'PROGRAMFILES'

Comment: What's with all the \r's in the output?

Comment: Not sure. That's directly from the error log in Apache. I removed the line C:/Apache24/cgi-bin/host-lookup-trace.py, referer: http://127.0.0.1/host-lookup-trace.html that follows the \r in each log entry

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
return self.data[key.upper()]
```

You mention that you can do this:

```
os.environ["ProgramFiles"]
```

But note that the key is `"ProgramFiles"`, not `"PROGRAMFILES"`. When you do `key.upper()`, you're taking whatever key you're passing in, even if it's the correct `"ProgramFiles"` string, and you're making it all upper-case

EDIT: And +1 to the comment: what's with all the `\r` everywhere?

EDIT 2: Never mind, seems like this is not the case

Comment: If you take a close look at the stacktrace, the line `return self.data[key.upper()]` is within `os.py`, i.e. the built-in `os` module.  This is not the problem.

Comment: That is correct @LukeWoodward - I'm not making that call in my code.

Comment: Also from the shell with upper case--- os.environ["PROGRAMFILES"]
'C:\\Program Files'

Answer (score 0):

Since os.environ was pulling the environment variables for the cgi/html instance that was calling the script, it did not have an entry for "ProgramFiles" in the dict -- thus the KeyError.

To fix it I added

```
os.environ["ProgramFiles"] = 'C:\\Program Files'
```

above my import scapy.

**I don't know that this is the correct way to do this, but for what I am looking to do it worked**